Consul unable to connect to Service in docker container
When I try and service docker through docker compose, it is unable to connect to Consul.
This is my application.properties.
spring.application.name=postservice

server.port=8080
spring.data.mongodb.database=posts
spring.data.mongodb.host=${MONGODB_HOST:MongoDBPosts}
spring.data.mongodb.port=${MONGODB_PORT:27017}

management.security.enabled=false
spring.cloud.consul.host=http://consul
spring.cloud.consul.port=8500
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.service-name=${spring.application.name}
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.instance-id=${spring.application.name}-4efb1523-76a3-f476-e6d8-452220593089

# Traefik configuration
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.tags[0]=traefik.enable=true
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.tags[1]=traefik.http.routers.${spring.application.name}.entrypoints=post
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.tags[2]=traefik.http.routers.${spring.application.name}.rule=PathPrefix('/path/')

This is my docker compose
version: "3.1"

networks:
  Pro290_network:
    external: false

services:

  Traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    container_name: traefik
    command:
        - '--api.insecure=true'
        - '--providers.consulcatalog=true'
        - '--providers.consulcatalog.prefix=traefik'
        - '--providers.consulcatalog.endpoint.address=consul:8500'
        - '--serversTransport.insecureSkipVerify=true'
        - '--entryPoints.web.address=:80'
        - '--entryPoints.developer_api.address=:8081'
        - '--log.level=DEBUG'
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8081:8081
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      # - ./traefik.yaml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yaml
    networks:
      - Pro290_network
    restart: always

  MongoDBPosts:
    container_name: MongoDBPosts
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    hostname: MongoDBPosts
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - Pro290_network

  PostService:
    container_name: postservice
    build: ./postservice
    image: postservice:latest
    networks:
      - Pro290_network
    ports:
      - "6001:8080"
    depends_on:
      - MongoDBPosts
      - Consul
    # labels:
    #   - "traefik.enable=true"
    #   - "traefik.http.routers.postservice.rule=Host(`postservice.Pro290_network.com`)"
    #   - "traefik.http.services.postservice.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
    #   - "traefik.http.routers.postservice.rule=PathPrefix(`/post/`)"

  Consul:
    image: hashicorp/consul:latest
    container_name: consul
    command: "agent -dev -client=0.0.0.0"
    ports:
      - "8500:8500"
    networks:
      - Pro290_network
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.consulcatalog.connect=true'
    restart: unless-stopped


And this is my main class
package pro290.post_service;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import okhttp3.*;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.IOException;
//import okhttp3.*;

@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class PostServiceApplication {

    @GetMapping(path = "/health")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void Health() {  }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        SpringApplication.run(PostServiceApplication.class, args);
        //registerToConsul();
    }

}


When I've changed the
spring.cloud.consul.host=http://consul

to
spring.cloud.consul.host=http://localhost

My docker container for my post service shows that there is an error connecting to consul when it's localhost, but not when it's consul.
